# String value with moment.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs

***My JS:***

```
...
var dateText='';
dateText = moment(scope.mtxMaxdate,'MM-DD-YYYY');
console.log(dateText);
...
```

I want to output my value example: `'12/12/2014'` but in the console i have:

```
Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _i: "17/12/2014", _f: "MM-DD-YYYY", _isUTC: false, _pf: Object…}
```

why..?

Comment: Why do you expect that `dateText` will be a string. [moment: String + Format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) creates a moment date object out of a string using the given format.

Comment: As `_i` shows your `scope.mtxMaxdate` is `17/12/2014` but you tell moment that the date you pass has to be in the format `MM-DD-YYYY`, so your date is invalid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in [momentjs docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/) you should use `.format()` function.

Something like this should do it :

```
var dateText='12-12-2014';
var dateObject = moment(dateText,'MM-DD-YYYY');
console.log(dateObject.format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
```

The format you give as an argument on second line is just the parse format.

I updated code, the fact that you use angular or not doesn't change a thing. I think what you do not understand is that moment js generates an **object** from a string date. You can then format this date object just as you want.

[Made a jsfiddle in case you don't get it.](http://jsfiddle.net/floo51/7m32cwbf/1/)

Comment: i have this dateText.format('MM-DD-YYYY') -- in the console: "Invalid date"

Comment: Ah. then scope.mtxMaxdate is probably malformed. if you console log it, what does it say?

Comment: @Mercer Updated post according to your comment

Answer (score 0):

But doing as per the accepted answer, there is a warning of Deprecation that is thrown. [Deprecation warning in moment js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39969570/deprecation-warning-in-moment-js)

However this doesn't seem to throw a warning now. Not sure if the resultant value is how you may need it to be.

```
> moment("12-25-1995", ["MM-DD-YYYY", "YYYY-MM-DD"]).format('MM-DD-YYYY')
> "12-25-1995"
```

If you have `Date` object convert it toString() and then apply the .format()