# How to get Unix timestamp using Bootstrap-datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, unix, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I am using 3rd party date time picker from https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

It is working fine, however, I'd like to get the value in Unix timestamp format. How do I do that? There is no formatting option for Unix. https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/#format

```
function getValue() {
    var date = $('#datetimepicker1').data('date');
    alert(date); // shows 05/25/2017 5:43 PM
}


<div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The eonasdan datetimepicker has a good API that you can use to programmatically interact with the picker.

You can use the [`date()`](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/#date) method that:

> Returns the component's model current date, a `moment` object or `null` if not set.

Since the value return by `date()` is a moment object you can use [`unix()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/unix-timestamp/) to get Unix timestamp (the number of seconds since the Unix Epoch).

Here a working sample:

```js
function getValue() {
  var date = $('#datetimepicker1').data("DateTimePicker").date();
  if( date ){
    alert(date.unix());
  }
}

$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
</div>

<button onclick="getValue()" class="btn btn-primary">Get value</button>
```

Remember that, as the [docs](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/) says:

> **Note** All functions are accessed via the `data` attribute e.g. `$('#datetimepicker').data("DateTimePicker").FUNCTION()`

Answer (score 5):

> **Short Answer: since that plugin work together with moment.js you can use the momentjs method `unix()`, like in the following way:**

```
moment($('#datetimepicker1').data('date')).unix()
```

**Update(I was testing on Internet Explorer 11)**

```
$('#datetimepicker1').data('DateTimePicker').date().unix()
```

Comment: the answer i was looking for

Comment: this actually gives the browser deprecation warning for moment.js as seen here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39969570/deprecation-warning-in-moment-js)

Comment: You are getting _Deprecation Warning_ because `$('#datetimepicker1').data('date')` returns a string that is not in [recognized format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/). This is not the right approach to get picker value, use the [`date()`](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/#date) method of the API instead.