# Chart js not working properly in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, chart.js

I'm using `Charts.js` to show some line charts that are working ok in Chrome or Firefox but not in Safari. From the source code everything seems ok, but the chart is not properly displayed in Safari.

The problem is with the first plot in the following link:

http://arquivodeopiniao.pt/entity-search/?q=ant%C3%B3nio+costa

Answer (score 1):

So, it was a problem related with [moment js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39969570/deprecation-warning-in-moment-js). It didn't want as input a list with string dates. Had to convert them to `moment(date,"YYYY-MM-DD")`:

```
var dados_temp = {{tag3_data.x|safe}}
var dados_moment = jQuery.map(dados_temp, function(x) { return moment(x,"YYYY-MM-DD"); });
```

Answer (score 0):

as a hacky workaround to the `MM-dd-yyyy` issue specific to safari/chart.js you can simply parse the date before hand and then do, for example, `'12/12/2021'.replace('/','-')` on the string and feed that into the chart.js data set instead of feeding it a date pipe parsed date it will work.

```
const date = '12/12/2021'.replace('/','-')
this.chartLabels.push(date)
```

as opposed to

```
const transDate = new Date(it.asOfDate)
this.chatLabels.push(this.datePipe.transform(transDate, 'MM-dd-yyyy'))
```