# MomentJS Using Locale If Deprecation Format Warning Provided

Tags: javascript, momentjs, locale

I'm using Moment JS and have encountered a bit of a catch 22 situation (but I'm presuming is fixable only I'm not sure how to).

Moment JS is giving me deprecation warnings which I did not previously receive (prior to deprecation I guess) therefore if I try the following.

```
moment(‘7/4/2018 6:00 AM’).locale(userLocale).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss’);
```

I get a warning

> moment.min.js:1 Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a
>   recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js
>   Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non
>   RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an
>   upcoming major release. Please refer to
>   http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.

My date is set correctly with the correct locale time applied despite this warning. However I'm a bit worried due to the warning therefore would like to fix it.

From the following it suggests I should use String + format in my Moment definition.

[Deprecation warning in moment js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39969570/deprecation-warning-in-moment-js)

However if I try

```
moment(‘7/4/2018 6:00 AM’,'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss').locale(userLocale)
```

It sets my Moment to an incorrect miliseconds value. It sets it to 61936855125000 which is an epoch of Tuesday, September 13, 3932 6:58:45 PM GMT+01:00 DST

If I wish to use .locale() with my moment, How can I create my moment correctly without incurring this deprecation warning?

Any help on this would be appreciated. I hope the question makes sense.

Comment: Well you gave it a date format that does not match the actual date string. The format you gave it is for dates that look like "2018-07-04 06:00:00".

Comment: @RedQueries di you check my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reason:**

The date i.e. 7/4/2018 6:00 AM (to be more specific MM/DD/YYYY format) you passed to moment() is **not supported** by momentjs library. This is the reason of getting warnings.

You can see supported `ISO 8601` and `RFC 2822` formats here : http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/

**Solution:**

Pass date in supported format (your is ISO 8601 format) to moment() instead of raw date like below:

```
var date = new Date('7/4/2018 6:00 AM');
var formattedDate = date.getFullYear() + "-" + parseInt(date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getDate() + " " + date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes() + ":" + date.getSeconds();

var supportedFormat = moment(formattedDate).locale('en').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
```

Check the below working code:

```js
var unsupportedFormat = moment('7/4/2018 6:00 AM').locale('en').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');

console.log(unsupportedFormat); //will show warning


var date = new Date('7/4/2018 6:00 AM');
var formattedDate = date.getFullYear() + "-" + parseInt(date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getDate() + " " + date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes() + ":" + date.getSeconds();

var supportedFormat = moment(formattedDate).locale('en').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
console.log(supportedFormat); // works fine
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your solution is *exactly* what Moment is warning about. The `Date()` constructor may or may not work, depending on the browser. The proper solution is to use a date format that actually matches the format in use.

Comment: Thank you VicJordan & Pointy for your help.  Apologies for the slow reply.  VicJordan, this is very detailed. Thank you.