# FullCalendar: Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I tried many things but not able to understand where I am lacking.
Tried different solutions as well.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      eventClick: function(eventObj, jsEvent, view) {
          $("#eventSubTitle").html(eventObj.patient);
          $("#eventLink").attr('href', eventObj.url);
          $("#eventHeader").html(eventObj.appointmentType);
          $("#eventStartTime").html(eventObj.start._i);
          $("#eventEndTime").html(eventObj.end._i);
          $("#appointmentId").val(eventObj.id);
          $("#eventDetailModal").modal('show');
      },
      timeFormat: 'hh:mm a',
      header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
      },
      defaultView: 'basicWeek',
      defaultDate: $.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', new Date()),
      editable: true,
      eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
      events:  ${raw(allList as String)},
      eventRender: function(event, element) { 
        element.find('.fc-title').append(" - " + event.patient); 
      },
      eventAfterRender: function (event, element, view) {
          var dataHoje = new Date();
          if (event.start < dataHoje && event.end > dataHoje) {
              element.css('background-color', 'green');
          } else if (event.start < dataHoje && event.end < dataHoje) {
              element.css('background-color', 'red');
          } else if (event.start > dataHoje && event.end > dataHoje) {
              element.css('background-color', '#000080');
          }
      }, 
    });
```

Can you suggest me some work around for the above code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deprecation warning in moment js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39969570/deprecation-warning-in-moment-js)

Answer (score 1):

Trouble is that `$.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', new Date())` will produce a string in mm/dd/yy format. But that's ambiguous - if today was the 3rd of January 2019, it would output `01/03/19`...but how can the calendar be sure it wasn't dd/mm/yy format - maybe you meant the 1st of March? It has no way to know. All it has is the raw string, without any context.

The solution here is simple: Don't use ambiguous date formats. In fact, don't use strings for dates at all if you can avoid it - use Date or MomentJS *objects* instead wherever possible.

(These objects carry the date information internally without bothering with the huge variety of human-readable string formats a date/time can appear in. They can be made to *output* the information in any of those formats, but that's not how they store it, so there's never any doubt about the meaning of the data.)

In this case you can easily avoid using strings:

```
defaultDate: new Date()
```

is perfectly valid - fullCalendar will accept any date string or object which is also accepted by the momentJS constructor (or it will accept a pre-made momentJS object). You don't need to format it at all.

But, since `defaultDate` will be today's date by default anyway, you can actually just remove that line entirely - you're just setting it to what is already the default value.

Of course it's possible you also have the same issue with your event data - I can't see that so I can't comment. But you should ensure your start and end dates are in a valid, unambiguous format so that fullCalendar can be sure what you mean.

See http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/,  https://fullcalendar.io/docs/defaultDate and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/moment for further documentation of this.