# Datatables Search Date Using Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable, datepicker

Using Datatables 1.10.19 and bootstrap-datepicker v1.8.0

I'm trying to filter my date column, but it doesn't appear to work and I'm not sure why. I'm able to filter all other data using the default search bar, but the datepicker doesn't seem to do anything. When I search for a date range I get no results?

I'm not sure if it's because of the date format i'm using (`dd-mm-yyyy`)?

I've created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/91ba8fus/4/) and my code is below;

*Note: please ignore any styling issues.*

**html**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-4 pull-right">
        <div class="input-group input-daterange">
            <input class="form-control date-range-filter" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" id="min-date" placeholder="From:" type="text">
            <div class="input-group-addon">
                to
            </div><input class="form-control date-range-filter" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" id="max-date" placeholder="To:" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="example" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>date</th>
            <th>Num</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Type</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="odd" role="row">
            <td class="sorting_1">27-03-2019</td>
            <td>521735</td>
            <td>£0.20</td>
            <td>overdue</td>
            <td>Card</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even" role="row">
            <td class="sorting_1">27-03-2019</td>
            <td>513938</td>
            <td>£1.20</td>
            <td>overdue</td>
            <td>Cash</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd" role="row">
            <td class="sorting_1">27-03-2019</td>
            <td>523693</td>
            <td>£0.20</td>
            <td>overdue</td>
            <td>Cash</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even" role="row">
            <td class="sorting_1">27-03-2019</td>
            <td>493645</td>
            <td>£0.10</td>
            <td>overdue renewed</td>
            <td>Cash</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd" role="row">
            <td class="sorting_1">27-03-2019</td>
            <td>521734</td>
            <td>£0.20</td>
            <td>overdue</td>
            <td>Card</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even" role="row">
            <td class="sorting_1">27-03-2019</td>
            <td>493646</td>
            <td>£0.10</td>
            <td>overdue renewed</td>
            <td>Cash</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd" role="row">
            <td class="sorting_1">27-03-2019</td>
            <td>523691</td>
            <td>£0.10</td>
            <td>overdue renewed</td>
            <td>Card</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even" role="row">
            <td class="sorting_1">27-03-2019</td>
            <td>523692</td>
            <td>£0.10</td>
            <td>overdue renewed</td>
            <td>Card</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd" role="row">
            <td class="sorting_1">27-03-2019</td>
            <td>523694</td>
            <td>£0.20</td>
            <td>overdue</td>
            <td>Cash</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even" role="row">
            <td class="sorting_1">26-03-2019</td>
            <td>506326</td>
            <td>£1.20</td>
            <td>overdue</td>
            <td>Card</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.input-daterange input').each(function() {
        $(this).datepicker('clearDates');
    });
    $('#example').DataTable({
        "order": [
            [0, "desc"]
        ],
        "columns": [{
            data: 'datePaid'
        }, {
            data: 'invoice'
        }, {
            data: 'amount'
        }, {
            data: 'chargeType'
        }, {
            data: 'paymentType'
        }, ],
        "columnDefs": [{
            targets: [0],
            type: 'date-eu'
        }],
    });
    // Extend dataTables search
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
        var min = $('#min-date').val();
        var max = $('#max-date').val();
        var createdAt = data[0] || 0; // Our date column in the table
        if (
            (min == "" || max == "") || (moment(createdAt).isSameOrAfter(min) && moment(createdAt).isSameOrBefore(max))) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
    // Re-draw the table when the a date range filter changes
    $('.date-range-filter').change(function() {
        $('#records').DataTable().draw();
    });
});
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: in fiddle, i think even after typing, search is working, is this partial working fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve expected result, update your dates to one format and check for the range

```
  var min = $('#min-date').val()? $('#min-date').val().split("-") : "";
  var max = $('#max-date').val()? $('#max-date').val().split("-") : "";

  var createdAt = data[0].split("-") || 0; // Our date column in the table

  createdAt = new Date(createdAt[1] + '/' + createdAt[0] + '/' + createdAt[2])
  min = min?new Date(min[1] + '/' + min[0] + '/' + min[2]): "";
  max = max?new Date(max[1] + '/' + max[0] + '/' + max[2]):"";
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/GebZNx

To avoid moment warning, use new Date('MM/DD/YYYY') for the dates in format -DD/MM/YYYY

Comment: Updated codepen and post, just added another check if max and min values are available or not

Comment: @TheOrdinaryGeek, it is due to the format conversion to maintain one format, Please refer this link for making valid date format - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39969570/deprecation-warning-in-moment-js

Comment: From moment documentation , DD-MM-YYYY needs to formatted to known format of moment -http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/

Comment: This deprecation warning is thrown when no known format is found for a date passed into the string constructor.
To work around this issue, specify a format for the string being passed to moment().

Comment: From official moment github issues, this might help -https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/3488

Comment: @TheOrdinaryGeek, updated codepen and post to avoid warning

Comment: any luck @TheOrdinaryGeek