# Is Fullcalendar v2.6.0 able to work on jQuery-3.3.1 and MVC 5?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, internet-explorer-11, fullcalendar-2

Is Fullcalendar v2.6.0 able to work on jQuery-3.3.1 and MVC 5? I have an old project which needs to be upgraded. I am using Visual Studio 2017 with jQuery-3.3.1, MVC 5.2.4 and moment.min.js 2.24 to recompile it, but I always got an error when I use IE 11:

> Unhandled exception at line 3827, column 3 in
>   http://localhost:61158/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js 0x800a138f - JavaScript
>   runtime error: Unable to get property 'format' of undefined or null
>   reference

When I use Google Chrome to debug it, I got an error message is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'format' of null

[image]

Anyone has any ideas? Thanks.

Sorry, this is my calendar code in index.cshtml.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            theme: true,
            aspectRatio: 2,
            defaultDate: '@DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")',
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            events: {
                url: '@Url.Action("GetCalendarEvents")',
                error: function () {
                    $('#script-warning').show();
                }
            },
            eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
                //set the values and open the modal
                //var winWidth = $(window).width();
                //var dialogWidth = winWidth * 0.5;
                var gdiv = $("#eventInfo");
                if (gdiv != null) gdiv.empty();

                $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

                var request = $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url:  calEvent.ajaxUrl,
                    data: {}
                });

                request.done(function (returndata) {
                    $("#eventInfo").html(returndata);

                });


                request.fail(function (jqXHR, status) {
                    alert("Error repopulating grid : " + status + "");
                });

                $.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });

            }
        });

    });

    </script>
```

Comment: [jQuery 3.3.1](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js) does not try to access any property called "format". It must be your code that you pass to jQuery to execute. Judging by your screenshot, it's the function that you pass to [`.each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand it. The old version of the project is running well. I upgraded the old version project from old version visual studio to visual studio 2017. I didn't change any code except for jquery 3.3.1 which existing in visual studio 2017. The old version project referenced jquery 1.9.1 min. Mine is using jquery 3.3.1 min. Do you think if some js files version cause this problem? Could you please tell me how to solve the problem you mentioned (.each function)? Thanks again.

Comment: Your code tries to access the format property on a null. You are not showing that code, so we cannot help fixing it.

Comment: Try to using the old JQuery version version(`<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-wS9gmOZBqsqWxgIVgA8Y9WcQOa7PgSIX+rPA0VL2rbQ="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`), instead of using the JQuery 3.3.1 version. Also, you could refer to [this document](https://fullcalendar.io/#demos) and [this demo](https://codepen.io/pen/?&editable=true&editors=001) to use the latest version of  Fullcalendar, it is no need to add JQuery reference when using it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, everyone. I have added my calendar code in my question. Could you please take a look? I prefer to use latest version of JQuery (3.3.1) because I am using Visual studio 2017, .net Framework 4.6.1 and mvc 5.2.4. I wouldn't like to down version for jQuery. So that means I have to upgrade FullCalendar's version? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded **fullCalendar** to **V3.9** and it is working right now. There is no error anymore except for a warning: **Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release. Please refer to momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date for more info.** But at lease the calendar is working correctly on my web app. Thanks for everyone's help. If you have any idea about the above warning, please let me know.

Comment: The warning is related to the date format, as the error message said 'it is not in a recognized ISO format.', more detail information, please check the [Moment.js Guides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39969570/deprecation-warning-in-moment-js-not-in-a-recognized-iso-format) and [Deprecation warning in moment js - Not in a recognized ISO format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39969570/deprecation-warning-in-moment-js-not-in-a-recognized-iso-format)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a JSFiddle using those library versions (the MVC version is irrelevant since that only affects server-side code): http://jsfiddle.net/g2np7wt9/2/

You didn't post your own code unfortunately, so I used a very basic calendar setup for the test:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    }
  });
});
```

It does indeed produce the error mentioned in your question, so the short answer is no, this combination of library versions doesn't work.

So your options are

a) downgrade the version of jQuery until the problem stops (2.2.4 seems to be the last version it works with, based on some quick tests)

or (probably better)

b) upgrade your version of fullCalendar, since 2.x is legacy now. 3.x is almost 100% API-compatible with 2.x, but does work with newer jQuery. See https://fullcalendar.io/blog/2016/09/feature-packed-releases. 4.x is a much bigger change but it may be worth it in the long run, since that's where the future lies in terms of new features, bug fixes etc. Also 4.x doesn't require jQuery or momentJS, so that headache would disappear entirely... see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/upgrading-from-v3.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I wouldn't like to downgrade the version of jQuery, because I am using Visual studio 2017, .net Framework 4.6.1 and mvc 5.2.4. So fullCalendar 2.x is not compatible with VS 2017 for sure, right? I must upgrade my fullCalendar to 3.x or 4.x for VS 2017, right? Because I have to report to my manager that the old code about calendar couldn't be used any more. Thanks.

Comment: The version of jQuery you use has absolutely nothing to do with Visual Studio (which is just an IDE used to write the code, not to execute it), the version of the .NET Framework (whose code runs server side, where jQuery runs in your browser) or the version of MVC (which is also server-side). None of those things place a restriction on your use of jQuery. Just because the MVC template deploys something by default doesn't mean you can't change it.

Comment: N.B. It's possible that some of the client-side code which can optionally be used with MVC, e.g. for client-side validation) might create a  requirement for a specific version of jQuery, but you'd have to check if that is in fact the case, and whether you actually need (or may in future need) any of that code in your particular application. Then you can make a more informed decision. But just upgrading to fullCalendar 3 might be the simplest option, since it's unlikely to require many (if any) changes to your calendar code (as per the blog link I provided). Might only be a 10 minute job.

Comment: Thank you so much! You gave me a very good suggestion. I only upgraded fullCalendar to V3.9 and kept .net Framework 4.6.1, MVC 5.2.4 and jQuery 3.3.1. It is working right now and no error any more except for a warning: **Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release. Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.**

Comment: That message means that somewhere you are giving fullCalendar / momentJS a date string in a non-standard or ambiguous format, and that it therefore cannot guarantee to understand it and process it correctly

Comment: If I had to guess I'd say it's probably `'@DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")'` which is the cause, because mm-dd-yyyyy is a potentially ambiguous format. For example, consider "01-03-2019". Is it 3rd Jan or 1st march? It depends on your culture. And once that is just a plain string given to the calendar it has no way to know what you originally intended. But anyway you don't even need this line of code because today's date is already the default date in fullCalendar. Adding that code doesn't change the calendar's behaviour. The documentation for `defaultDate` tells you that.

Comment: Thanks you so much for your answer, ADyson. It is clear to me now!