# Adding days to a moment object is return same moment object

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs, addition

I've a moment object to which I'm trying add some days.
However, it is returning the same moment object as a result.

But, if I simply try to do it on the current date, it works fine.

Also, note that, I always receive a moment object to which I need to add the days.

Code:

```
const someDate = moment('22-03-2020');
console.log(someDate.add(5, 'days');
```

someDate is something I receive from the server and is always a moment object.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

> "Deprecation warning in moment js - Not in a recognized ISO format"
>   if you provide not valid ISO format for more check here information
>   [Deprecation warning in moment js - Not in a recognized ISO format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39969570/deprecation-warning-in-moment-js-not-in-a-recognized-iso-format)

```
    // Recommended format: YYYY/MM/DD


 const someDate = moment('2020-03-22');
 console.log(someDate.add(5, 'days').format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
```

[image]

[Test here](https://runkit.com/nodecode/momentnode/1.0.0)

Comment: Or you can be explicit: `moment('22-03-2020', 'DD-MM-YYYY', true)`

Answer (score 1):

You should specify what format you used, like so:

```
const someDate = moment('22-03-2020', 'DD-MM-YYYY')
const newDate = someDate.add(5, 'days')
console.log(newDate)
```

To format a moment object, you just have to add `.format()` like so:

```
console.log(newDate.format())
```

Comment: console still return Moment Object

Comment: @ManjeetThakur, I've updated my answer. You can put `.format()` to format your Moment Object.